# Diff the database in before action and after action

Tags: python, ruby, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo DB,

Is there any way to let me check `What's the difference between before action and after action on the database ?`

Ex: when I do a create action, how can I get the difference before and after action in the DB

Because I have to ensure that is no other side effect after I do a action on the DB.

I can think of to dump all the database content before the action,

After doing the action dump all the database again,

And then diff the both dumped-data.

I'm familiar with Ruby and Python script,

Is there any quick way to let me achieve the job? Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

The main reason why I need this is that we never know what the actual action in the database, when I do some requests via web API.

The developers tell you that if you do add record request, then there will only one item appended  in the database, but you never know what it really did in the database.
Therefore we need to check it by inspect the database.

Comment: Wow... I'd first ask: "why do you need this?" and "surely there's a better way to achieve what you need than this?" ... so can you edit your question and explain why this is necessary - you never know, we might find a much simpler solution for you.

Comment: Why don't you trust the developers? Why do you need to know that it's more (or less) than one record? why does it matter to know this?

Comment: If your job is a QA, you should stand on the other side of developer. :)

Comment: Ok, so that's the kind of info that you need to add to your question... and any other info that is related to your question. :)